# How to create custom python function without syntax error

Tags: python, function

I am getting error creating my own function searcher. Problem is, it don't accept strings or numbers. How to make it accept my any string and any numbers.

Output error:

```
File "searcher.py", line 35
    if len(str(val)) >= 5 and len(str(val)) <= 10 :
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the buggy code then it won't work good with characters.

```
        try:
        val = str(card)
    if len(str(val)) >= 5 and len(str(val)) <= 10 :
        for site in paste_sites:
                    query = '{} {}'.format(site, card)
                    qlist.append(query)
```

What I want, It should accept any character length of alphabets and digits

Comment: Can't, my geany in linux, won't accept the code then.

Comment: @HaroonAhmad, you need to fix it on the OP or nobody will help you because the code doesn't make any sense the way it is right now. Please, check ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and finally ["How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I edited zillion times for you guys, but no use.

Here is the solution:
        val = card
        if len((val)) >= 1 and len((val)) <= 10:

Problem was, it was accepting digits only as str value was in placed.